# How to return more decimal places in pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm a pine-script newbie, I use close to get the price but the value returned is only 3 decimal places

Can I make it show more decimal places?

thank you all

```
//@version=5
strategy("test", overlay=true)
log.info('{0}', close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, add format and specify precision:

```
price = close
formattedPrice = str.format("{:.5f}", price)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved

`price = str.format("{0, number, #.########}", close)
log.info('{0}', price)`